# Can inserted records be returned in Save method in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework-6

I found some code which says how to get the identity column as a return for inserted rows. But can we get the record in the same call?

Below code shows how to get the id only.

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
     context.MyEntities.AddObject(myNewObject);
     context.SaveChanges();

     int id = myNewObject.Id; // Yes it's here
}
```

Comment: As you noticed - EF *already* does this for you, automagically and without you having to do *anything* - just read out the `id` after `SaveChanges` and you're done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"myNewObject" should be updated with the information you saved. Even the Id property should now contain the Id of your record.